# I am not able to save image into Folder

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to save a image in specified folder but it doesn't saving image but code is working for excel file storing...did i missed something here....please suggestions needed.

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(imgUploadControl.PostedFile.FileName);
string folder = Server.MapPath("~/Files/");
imgUploadControl.PostedFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(folder, filename));
string filePath = Path.Combine(folder, filename);
imglogo.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + imgUploadControl.FileName);
```

Comment: check this link will help you. http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/

Comment: Use try-catch block and see if it is throwing any exception